# How to check and extract only numbers from a string with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dynamically generated string like:

```
'\n\n\n0\n1\n\n\n\n\n\n'
or 
'\r\n\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n1\r\n\r\n'
or 
'\r\n\r\n\r\n1/2\r\n\r\n1/2\r\n\r\n'
```

I wonder what is the best way to extract only the number 1, 0 or 1/2 with python 3

What I am doing now is use \r\n or \n to split the string and check each element in the list - I don't like my own way to process, there should be a better and elegant way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Look into [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on whitespace to retrieve words. Then turn each word into a number, a fraction. Then convert to floating point, in case you find that more convenient.

(No need to wrap it with `list()`, if you're happy with a generator.)

```
from fractions import Fraction

def get_nums(s):
    """Extracts fractional numbers from input string s."""
    return list(map(float, (map(Fraction, s.split()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It all can be done as a single one-liner using list-comprehension:

```
numbers=[float(i) for i in myString.split()]
```

The split method of the string class will take care of the excess whitespace for you.

Comment: Thank you but sorry there is exception using your code

Comment: Damn it i forgot about float("1/2"). I guess you could replace float(i) with eval(i) but that would be bad in terms of "best practices".